# PyInstaller app with cefpython throws ERROR:icu_util.cc(133)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data receiv

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, cefpython

I've been developing a **Tkinter** GUI application with **CEFPython** for browser integration. My application runs smoothly when executed as a Python script. However, I've been running into issues when trying to compile it into a standalone executable using **PyInstaller**.

Here's the PyInstaller command I've been using: `pyinstaller -i assets/icon.ico -F -w bot.py`

After running this command, PyInstaller successfully creates an executable in the dist directory. When I run the executable, however, I receive an error message in the debug.log file located in the same directory as the executable. The error message is as follows: `ERROR:icu_util.cc(133)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received`.

I've tried researching solutions online, but so far I've come up empty. I'd greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue what it came to be was the files icudtl.dat and natives_blob.bin needed to be in the dist/{your_package}/cefpython3 folder

what I ended up doing for now is adding two lines to the Analysis.datas list

```
cef = get_cefpython_path()
datas = [
 ...
 ("%s/icudtl.dat" % cef, "cefpython3"),
 ("%s/natives_blob.bin" % cef, "cefpython3")
] 
a = Analysis(
 ...
 datas=datas,
)
```

credit
[failed to create executable with pyinstaller and cefpython on Linux (Invalid file descriptor to ICU data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64339096/failed-to-create-executable-with-pyinstaller-and-cefpython-on-linux-invalid-fil)